# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found

Tags: java, jsf

Here is my ManagedBean

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import model.Client;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


import service.ClientService;



    public class ClientBeanManger implements Serializable {
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

         @Autowired
         private ClientService clientService;
         private Client client; 


        public void init () {
              }


         public Client getClient() {
            return client;
        }


        public void setClient(Client client) {
            this.client = client;
        }


         public void saveClient(Client client){
             clientService .add(client);

         }
```

I called saveclient method like in :

```
<tr>
       <td><p:commandButton id="addclient" value="Add" actionListener="{clientBean.saveClient}"/></td>

       </tr>
```

I have looked lots of examples about jsf .Everybody calls like I have called the method.What is the wrong which I haven't seenn i still not work since 2 days

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
              <p:commandButton id="addclient" value="Add" actionListener="#{clientBean.saveClient(someClientObject)}"/>
       </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: i try this line command by not worked , another execption appear

Comment: 'java.lang.NullPointerException controller.ClientBeanManger.saveClient(ClientBeanManger.java:57)
'

Comment: someClientObject is a object of Client class!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `action` instead of `actionListener`

like :
Change this

```
<p:commandButton id="addclient" value="Add" actionListener="#{clientBean.saveClient(someClientObject)}"/>
   </td>
```

to this

```
<p:commandButton id="addclient" value="Add" action="#{clientBean.saveClient}"/>
   </td>
```